# MacVim: share named registers across windows?

Tags: vim, window, buffer

I want to share named register buffers across MacVim windows (as I would across buffers within a single instance).  In other words, let's say I mark a position, m, and go somewhere else:

I yank some text into register a, from current point to 'm:   "a'm

Then I go to another window (no, I dont mean another split view in the same
window...) and want to paste:  "ap

What is a good way to share named registers across all instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [YankRing](https://github.com/vim-scripts/YankRing.vim) plug-in. It "maintains a history of previous yanks, changes and deletes." I think it will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The different top-level windows of MacVim are different instances of Vim with their own state, which makes this hard. As far as I can tell, you have two options:

1. Use the `"+` or `"*` registers, which both use the Mac system clipboard. (As an aside: in X11 they are different, but all other GUIs treat them the same). MacVim has the standard <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>/<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd> bound to use `"+`. Unfortunately that only gives you one shared buffer.
2. Keep a text file with your registers in it, as explained by max at [Make vim yankings global via a shared text file](https://superuser.com/questions/266547/make-vim-yankings-global-via-a-shared-text-file).

Answer (score 1):

Top level windows have use different vim instances, so they don't share the same register, but different tabs do share the same registers.

So as a quick and dirty simple solution, open the files in different tabs of the same window to share their named registers.