# How to share register within vim processes

Tags: vim

I often start multiple vim processes, how can i share the register among them? i have investigate the +clientserver feature, but i think it's not an easy way to do that.

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MacVim: share named registers across windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640932/macvim-share-named-registers-across-windows)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `:wv`/`:rv` to write/read viminfo file to share register content across processes.

Comment: can you please expand on this answer? Are these vim commands?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

At least not easily/seemlessly. Either you use only one instance or you use multiple instances which can't share anything, actually, without a lot of work (temporary files, sending commands to a server and lots of  `autocmd`s). You can still have access to the system clipboard from multiple instances but that's probably not enough for what you want